# Django group-logic with Models (manytomany-relationship)

Tags: python, django, logic, m2m

I have a question about how to implement some group-logic with Django, so here's a picture to help understand what I'm aiming for:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpKJA.png]

Edit:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8SEW.png]

So what I'm trying to get is:

- There is a a primary group (Group1) and when a member joins the subgroups Group2 and 3 - he will be added to Group1 automatically
- There can be members in both Group2 and Group3 - they shouldn't exist twice in Group1 though.

If it's possible to achieve, I would also like to have the following feature:

- Group4 is again a subgroub of Group3, if a member joins Group4, he should automatically be saved as a member of Group3 and thereby of Group1 as well.

At the moment I have the following models:

```
#models.py
class MyGroup(models.Model):

    label = models.CharField(_('Label'), max_length=30)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('MyUser', null=True, blank=True)
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    # parents could be renamed to supersets/masters as well

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(
        MyGroup, through=MyGroup.members.through, blank=True
    )
```

Thanks in advance for any answers - it would also help to know if its actually possible to achieve: Then I'll know that I won't be wasting hours, on figuring out a way how to do it, for nothing.

## Edit:

I tried to do it this way:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.parents is not None:
        list_of_parents = self.parents.all()
        for x in range(0, len(list_of_parents)):
            new_list_of_users = list(set(list_of_parents[x].members.all()) | set(self.members.all()))
            list_of_parents[x].members = new_list_of_users
            super(MailingList, list_of_parents[x]).save(*args, **kwargs)
    super(MailingList, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this works somewhat, but has very undelightful flaws as well:

- Users will only be saved in the parent-group, when I save the members over the groups-menu (as this is a save-function for the Group-model) - I could add another save-function in the User-model as well, but its not getting much better
- The big issue here is, that I can no longer add new groups, because I will get the following error:
  `"<MyGroup: group5>" needs to have a value for field "from_mygroup" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`
- Last but not least, I think the way to implement things over the save-function will not perform very well - especially, when there are loads of members in each group...

Comment: with computer ANYTHING is possible.  I would suggest that you put your group assignment logic in the save function of a group assignment form (where you setup the ability to add a user to a group. unless you get "fancy" and setup inheritance for groups.

Comment: if using your current setup; parents should be a ForiegnKey, as each MyGroup can only have 1 parent (or should only be able to have one parent).

Comment: I would actually like to keep the ManyToMany realtion, as I'd like to be able to have another primary group (e.g. Group5) while Group2 has Group1 and Group5 as a parent.

Comment: then rename parent to primary or master.  you current diagram would have: Group 1: no parent, Group 3 ->Group 1 parent, Group 2->Group 1 parent; Group 4->Group 3 parent.  To add your "group 5" simply Group 1->Group 5 parent.

Comment: no Group5 should not be the parent of Group1, but rather be a primary group of its own. Group2 can have Group1 and Group5 as a parent (but Group3 is not necessarily part of Group5)

Comment: i see where you are going... then what you have I think will work; i would personally rename parent to supersets or i guess parents (to indicate that it can be part of more than one superset).

Comment: ok, thats no problem - the variables are placeholders atm - just trying to get things done :) - will add another picture to clear this up!